# How to post a file to localhost without breaking it apart? (using ajax/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm now trying to send a json text file from my index.html to a localhost server.

I've read a lot about this topic and I know I can use multipart/formdata to break a file into scraps -> send to server via http -> append them back at server side.

But what if I just want to send a text file with a small size? (btw I don't want to read the file at client side. I want to send the whole file) Is that doable?

Comment: The file gets broken down automatically by the stack and put back together. You don't have to do it yourself unless your server is a pure TCP client and skips the higher levels of the OSI stack. Not sure what your problem is, every http framework will put the file back together for you